# Problem with configurating dhcp server

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I'm having a bit of a problem with forwarding the internet from server to client. I've done everything this site told me to
`https://zse.rzeszow.pl/ubuntu/routing-dhcp-ubuntu-server`,

 but client still doesn't have connection with basic 8.8.8.8 nor google.com for example.
This is my code in "/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf"

```
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.10.10.40 10.10.10.60
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 10.10.10.1;
}
host ubuntu-gnome {
hardware ethernet "adres MAC"
fixed address 10.10.10.10
```

Any idea can be helpful :)

Comment: DHCP servers will give addresses, but you need to set up special NAT / Route rules to MASQUERADE the traffic.  This is done in Section 3 of your document - did you go through Section 3 yet?  If you have, show `sudo iptables -L -n -v -t NAT` output please.

Comment: i did the ip tables and the outcome of the command you told me looks like this "iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table 'NAT': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded. (but if i type it with lower case nat it shows this = https://gyazo.com/23100b7433b36b3cc6f9e31c6e285dbc

Comment: I mistyped it oops.  Use lowercase `nat` instead of NAT.  Darned autocorrect!

Comment: there https://gyazo.com/23100b7433b36b3cc6f9e31c6e285dbc

Comment: Do you know if the client was successful obtaining an IP address via your DHCP server? Is your client able to ping by IP address or just not via DNS loopkup? Use tcpdump (or wireshark) to verify client packets arriving at your server. Use another tcpdump session to monitor the same packets on the internet side. Verify state of net.ipv4.ip_forward.

Comment: nothing works :( or im just dumb i don't know