# How do I let my client to use internet via using iptables in Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, iptables, dhcp

I've got setup dhcp server who is listening for IP requests in private server. When client connects to it, he gets an IP, gateway and dns address. Server can ping him and client ping server, but client doesn't want to get internet connection and i want to know if its either my config or wrong commands. the ip_forward is set to 1.

DHCP config

```
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
range 10.10.10.40 10.10.10.60;
option routers 10.10.10.1;
}`
```

Interfaces config

```
auto lo enp0s3 enp0s8

iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
iface enp0s8 inet static
   address 10.10.10.11
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

.

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "addresses below" -d "-||-" -j MASQUERADE
```

[iptables results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB5IT.png)

how to setup iptables, cus im confused :c

Comment: Please edit your question, adding your iptables rule set directly. They do not look correct.

Comment: so whats the correct way of putting the iptables

Comment: I do not know, still trying to make sense of things, including your previous question. You list the router as being at 10.10.10.1, so that is where your client should be trying to send packets via. So, they wouldn't go via your server at 10.10.10.11 anyhow.

Comment: it doesn't need to be with those 10's, if you have a configuration fixing my problem, i would be thankful for it.

Comment: if i would go to put the client in the dhcp config file (the host "name" etc.) would that let him use internet?

Comment: We have communication issues. I do not know if you really have a separate router (10.10.10.1) or your are trying to be the router at 10.10.10.10. But you need to tell the client, with his lease.

Comment: where is the sub-net 192.168.1.0/24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:
enp0s3 is on the 192.168.1.0/24 sub-net, which in turn goes to internet.
enp0s8 is on the 10.10.10.0/24 sub-net, at 10.10.10.11 and is local.
10.10.10.1 doesn't actually exist.
The client is somewhere in the 10.10.10.40 - 10.10.10.60 pool.

Then your basic router type iptables rule needs to be:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

And your options router statement needs to be:

```
option routers 10.10.10.11;
```

EDIT: based on your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310853/problem-with-configurating-dhcp-server), your client might be outside of your dynamic address pool, getting its IP address of 10.10.10.10 based on MAC (Machine Address Code). Such is fine, but it's lease will not appear in the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` file.

Comment: I;ve manage to make it work, but now I can't see the address in dhcp-lease-list (i restarted machine and there is only one iptables rule)

Comment: If your client is getting IP address from outside the dynamic pool, as suggested for 10.10.10.10 from your other question, then no it will not appear in the leases file. If it is from the pool, then it should be in the file. If my answer worked for you then please upvote and accept it.

Comment: yeah ive read it, thanks for help man :)